# limit of $\lim_{n\to \infty} (-1)^{n-1} \sin(\pi \sqrt{n^2 + 0.5n + 1})$ what am I doing wrong?

Tags: limits

I have to evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty} (-1)^{n-1} \sin(\pi \sqrt{n^2 + 0.5n + 1})\,\,where \,\,n\,\epsilon\,N$$

what I would do is just factor out $n^2$ in the sqrare root, then just make the $\frac{0.5}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ term zero.

$$\sin{\left(\pi\sqrt{n^2(1+\frac{0.5}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2})}\,\right)}$$
n goes to infinity so this becomes :-

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \sin{\left(n\pi\right)}$$
now $\sin n\pi$ is just $0$ so the answer should be $0$

But the answer is $\sin{\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}$

Could someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong

Comment: You should replace $\sqrt{n^2+0.5n+1}$ with $n+0.25$ instead of $n$.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz wouldnt that be wrong, $(n+0.25)^2 = n^2 + 0.5n + 0.0625$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that as $n\to\infty$, $\sqrt{n^2 +0.5n + 1}$ diverges, and $\sqrt{n^2 +0.5n + 1} -n \neq 0$. We have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n^2 +0.5n + 1} -n &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{(n + 0.25)^2 + 1 - 0.25^2} - n\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(\sqrt{n^2 +0.5n + 1} - n)(\sqrt{n^2 +0.5n + 1} + n)}{\sqrt{n^2 +0.5n + 1} + n}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{0.5n + 1}{\sqrt{n^2 +0.5n + 1} + n} = \frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}

Comment: alright, but when we factor out $n^2$, there are two terms $\frac{0.5}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}$, so should'nt they become zero

Comment: Note that the limit actually diverges to infinity. Only the limit of the difference between $\sqrt{n^2 +0.5n + 1}$ and $n$ exist, and it would be $\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Begin by noting that

$$(-1)^{n-1}\sin(n\pi +X)=-\sin(X)$$

then, use the fact that when $ x\to 0$,

$$\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac x2(1+\epsilon(x))$$
with $\lim_{x\to 0}\epsilon(x)=0$.

So

$$\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}=1+\frac{1}{4n}(1+\epsilon(n))$$
with $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\epsilon(n)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Before $1+\frac{0.5}{n}+\frac1{n^2}$ can "become" $1$, it is greater than $1$. And so when it multiplies by $n^2$, you get something greater than $n^2$. And it turns out that it is still greater enough than $n^2$ to make a difference.

The hint in the comments is to use $n^2+0.5n+1=(n+0.25)^2+\frac{15}{16}$. Then you have $(n+0.25)\sqrt{1+\frac{15}{16(n+0.25)^2}}$. At this point your intuition works out to be correct, and $1+\frac{15}{16(n+0.25)^2}$ goes to $1$ quickly enough. But more should be done to prove this.